# SQL search query based on string - numbers separated with comma

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I have a `Product` model that has a `string` property contains numbers separated comma. Also have a table related to this model.

```
public class Product 
{
  ....
  public string RelatedUserIdSet { get; set; }
}

//different variants
row1 - RelatedUserIdSet = "1,3,43,555,90,4";
row2 - RelatedUserIdSet = "3445,737,34,54";
row3 - RelatedUserIdSet = "3445,88,44,54,3";
row4 - RelatedUserIdSet = "";
row5 - RelatedUserIdSet = "44";
row6 - RelatedUserIdSet = "11,5,655,89,99,447,1455,12,112,658";
.....
```

I need a help to create a sql query to find products that it's `RelatedUserIdSet` contains given keyword. 
Assume that, if keyword will be `keyword = 3`, we'll get `model1` and `model3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In relational databases, you should be storing this information as a junction table.  But, that is not how it is stored in the source system.  In SQL Server, you can solve this with `like`:

```
where ',' + RelatedUserIdSet + ',' like '%,' + cast(keyword as varchar(255)) + ',%'
```

Note the use of commas to delimit both the set contents and the query string.  This prevents `3` from matching `3445`.

Comment: RelatedUserIdSet' length is not very large, that is why i did not need to use extra table for this. This way is suitable for my sytem. 
Excellent code. Thanks